# Django delete confirmation view displaying variable name instead of information

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me with the following scenario?
I have 3 tables like bellow. 1 & 2 is my data tables.
And 3 keeps the relationship with 1 & 2.

```
1.Qa table
-------------
|ID |   QA  |
-------------
|1  |qa1    |
|2  |qa2    |
|3  |qa3    |
-------------
a field of my Qa model
tags = select2.fields.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, verbose_name='Tag')

2.Tag table
-------------
|ID |   Tag |
-------------
|1  |tag1   |
|2  |tag2   |
|3  |tag3   |
-------------

3.qa tag relation
---------------------
|ID |QA_ID  |Tag_ID |
---------------------
|1  |1      |2      |
|2  |1      |3      |
|3  |2      |1      |
|4  |3      |1      |
|5  |3      |2      |
|6  |3      |3      |
---------------------
```

> Edit

**qa model**

```
class Qa(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Question')
    tags = select2.fields.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, verbose_name='Tag')
    """
    And some more fields.
    """

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)
        verbose_name = 'QA data'
```

**tag model**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_text = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, verbose_name='Tag')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'QA Tag'
```

※I do not have qa_tag model

If I delete the list of Tag (from above 2.Tag Table), it redirects to the confirmation table. And it displays the list with some variable name like bellow

- Tag: tag1

  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object
  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object
- Tag: tag2

  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object
- Tag: tag3

  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object
  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object
  - Qa-tag relation: Qa_tags object

what I really expect is (something user readable information)

- Tag: tag1

  - Qa-tag relation: qa2
  - Qa-tag relation: qa3
- Tag: tag2

  - Qa-tag relation: qa1
- Tag: tag3

  - Qa-tag relation: qa1
  - Qa-tag relation: qa2
  - Qa-tag relation: qa3

I cannot figure out why this happens and how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

> Edit2:

After Daniel Roseman's Answer I tried to create an own model to handle the many to many relation

```
class Qa_Tag(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.tag.tag_text
```

And the qa model changed as below

```
class Qa(models.Model):
    ....

    tags = select2.fields.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, through = 'Qa_Tag', verbose_name='Tag')

    ....
```

It shows the values when deleting. But my I had to register Qa_Tag in admin.py and only way I could assign the relation is though Qa_Tag view.

Now I know the reason is there is no `__str__()` method for my Qa_Tag table but still couldn't figure out how to write a model class for generated qa_tag table without braking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your models, but almost certainly you have not defined a `__str__` method on the Qa_tags class.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Roseman for your reply. But I do not have a Qa_tags class. Am i going to need one? (I just edit my question)