# Django admin showing object ID instead of __str__ when deleting

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm not sure if this is a bug, by design or something I've done.
I'm seeing the same issue as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492400/django-delete-confirmation-view-displaying-variable-name-instead-of-information) when deleting an item with a M2M relationship where the object ID is returned instead of **str**.

The **str** is set correctly and displays correctly otherwise, just not when deleting an item. The object ID shows up instead.

I've tested by creating a new Django project and a simple model with 2 classes related by M2M but get the same thing.

The only way I've found, which isn't ideal, is to use the "through" option on the field.

One I have many relationships like this in various models.

Two, returning **str** on the intermediate model I have to display both fields so that it makes sense when deleting from either of the related models.

Anyone have any thoughts? Is using "through" the only option?

Comment: Do you have an __str__ method on the m2m relation model as well?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali I have it set on both of the related models themselves. Or are you referring to the intermediate Django creates?

Comment: ye, I am referring to the intermediate created by django. If you define that model yourseld and add __str__ method there, I think your problem should resolve. I do not know if there is a way to update __str__ method of the intermediate model if not defined explicitly

Comment: @OzgurAkcali how can that be done without using the "through" option on the m2m relation? Just create the model and it will/should override?

Comment: I do not know a way, but why do you not want to use through option? That's no "non-ideal", if you want to customize the behavior of the intermediate model, which is what you want to do in a way, that is the way to go. This is mostly used for adding additional field to the relation, but I think your goal also requires this.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali I didn't want to have to create an intermediate model for every m2m that I have, which isn't many at the moment but could be more. Was hoping there was another way to do it without having to use the "through" option because of that. It does seem to be the only way that I can find.

Comment: Keep looking though, there is no way that I know of, but maybe there is way. Update me as well if you find a way please.